# Canonical question / answer for porting Ubuntu Touch

Tags: discussion, canonical-questions

We [recently discussed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/conversation/ubuntu-touch-porting) in the [Ask Ubuntu General Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) the fact that we do not have a canonical question / answer for porting Ubuntu Touch to new hardware.

This has led to a proliferation of questions about specific devices:

- [port Ubuntu Touch to unsupported Tablet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335915/port-ubuntu-touch-to-unsupported-tablet)
- [Can someone help me get Ubuntu touch on my Huawei Ascend y300?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350506/can-someone-help-me-get-ubuntu-touch-on-my-huawei-ascend-y300)
- ...

So, in light of that, I created [a question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350558/how-do-i-go-about-porting-ubuntu-touch-to-xyz-device) that we can use as a canonical question. We can then close / flag the others as dupes of mine.

Thoughts?

Comment: All we need is someone to write a detailed enough answer which also provides links to routinely-updated guides/pages while keeping key points in the answers, no?

Comment: Whoever that do the answer should have a experience with the process too!

Comment: Don't confuse people asking to install Ubuntu Touch with people wanting to port Ubuntu Touch. Your examples display the difference quite clearly and they're quite separate issues.