# Can we have a canonical post about Ubuntu Phone hardware?

Tags: discussion, canonical-questions

Ever since the first Ubuntu phone shipped, we have been getting the occasional question about its availability in some place or the other. [For installing on other phones](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7385/canonical-question-answer-for-porting-ubuntu-touch), we have [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support) as the question to which we close as dupe. Can we have one for Ubuntu phones as well?

For example:

- [Ubuntu phone availability](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588680/ubuntu-phone-availability)
- [When will the Ubuntu phones be available in India?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/587272/when-will-the-ubuntu-phones-be-available-in-india)
- [Ubuntu Phones for the US](https://askubuntu.com/questions/585579/ubuntu-phones-for-the-us)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/585320/ubuntu-phone-in-united-states
- [Ubuntu phone release in India](https://askubuntu.com/questions/582819/ubuntu-phone-release-in-india?s=56|0.0000)
- [When is Ubuntu Phone/Touch coming to the U.S.?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574932/when-is-ubuntu-phone-touch-coming-to-the-u-s)

Comment: I see problem: according to our FAQ/help we do not do hardware on AU ;)

Comment: I know. I imagine these users are either unaware of that, or thinking that they are not asking for hardware recommendations (which I'd agree with).

Comment: Maybe: make a topic; answer the topic; make it community and close it? But Ill let a mod answer this ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind That's what I'd like. But I honestly don't know anything about Ubuntu Phone and don't care, so I'm hoping someone who does can make such a post. BTW, post that as answer. It's definitely one way to solve this.

Comment: @muru - doesnt this cover your question? http://askubuntu.com/questions/235665/where-can-i-get-a-device-with-ubuntu-for-phones-pre-installed

Comment: @fossfreedom I suppose. A bunch of VTCs coming up.

Comment: Nice @fossfreedom :) and why not make that an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can I humbly suggest the following for the canonical (no pun intended) Q&A:

- [Where can I get a device with 'Ubuntu for phones' pre-installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235665/where-can-i-get-a-device-with-ubuntu-for-phones-pre-installed)

I've made the answer a community wiki - so lets all add the new phones when they appear together with the area of the world that they are applicable for, to that answer rather than having a 101+ answers when (hopefully) every man and his dog starts producing a ubuntu phone.